# How to place my dropdown CSS menu bar on top of my jQuery picture rotator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web page and I have an issue with my jQuery add-on. I initially installed the add on to have an image rotator and after that I created a drop down menu bar. My problem is that when I put the cursor on the drop down tab it drops behind the jQuery rotator! Can anyone suggest a solution before I upload my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: before code upload, suggestion would be: use google :)

Comment: I tried but I didn't actually know how to express it! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css z-index is probably the solution you're after

Comment: Oh thank you so much! My brain stopped working and I couldn't remember that! Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: np i would really appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct =)

Answer (score 1):

Breezer is right the z-index is probably what you will need or you can look into positioning the drop down menu above the rotator using some margins